# How to scroll restaurant detail page like talabat app using flutter

Tags: flutter

I searched a lot to be able to scroll the restaurant page (the page contains the restaurant details and also the menu of the meals) such as the Talabat application and I tried many ways, but I did not find the right solution. Can you help, please?. Can you help me please?

[image]

Comment: you want to scroll only below list?

Comment: Yes, and when you click on any of the meal sections, the secondary scroll works and the main page scroll remains fixed. You can download the application, please, to understand what I mean. I wanted to add a video with the question, but I could not do that.

Comment: Can you add your code inside column widget? please let me know and aslo told you use ListView widget also?

Comment: Sorry, I can't add the code here because it's not organized because of the big changes to it, but I switched the use of listview inside the list view, but it didn't work.  Scroll works for main listview and I tried sliver list and NestedScroll view but it didn't work

Comment: ok refer my answer below hope it helps you

Comment: In short, I want to make a page in which there are two scrolls (main scrolling and sub scrolling), when clicking on any of the meal sections works only sub scroll, and when scrolling anywhere on the screen to the top it works main scrolling and if main scrolling at the top works sub  Scrolling, almost like a sliderlist view, but the problem is that when you click on any of the sections of the meals it goes to the top of the entire screen and not just the meals displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try below Structure

```
Column(
    children:[
       Your 1st Widget(),// no scroll its fixed
       Your 2nd Widget(),// no scroll its fixed
       //below your scrolling widget

      Expanded(
         child:ListView(),
       ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but this method does not work because if scrolling is done for the listview the widget does not scroll, the widget must also scroll

Comment: try ListView.builder instead of ListView(), if you get List of items

Comment: Not a complete answer but I am using this package scrollable_positioned_list

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following, and it is close to the solution, but I want the best. I feel that there is still a delay in scrolling mainScroll.

```
@override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   subScrollController.addListener(() {
     mainScrollController.position.moveTo(mainScrollController.position.pixels+subScrollController.position.pixels);
   });
 }

 Scaffold(
     body: Container(
       //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       child:  ListView(
         controller: mainScrollController,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         children: [
           Container(
             height: 100,
             color: Colors.red,
             child: MaterialButton(
               child: Text("button"),
               onPressed: (){
                 subScrollController.position.moveTo(400);
               },
             ),
           ),

           Container(
             height: 100,
             color: Colors.yellow,
           ),
           Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
               child:
           ListView.builder(
             controller: subScrollController,
             //controller: _scrollController,
             physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

             itemBuilder: (b, i) {
               return Container(
                 height: 50,
                 color: Colors.green,
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                 child: Text(
                   i.toString(),
                 ),
               );
             },
             itemCount: 30,
           ))
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can I get a better solution in your opinion?